# My adapter has stopped working, but only the usb port, and only on my windows machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

I have both a work computer (a macbook pro) and a personal computer (an intel machine running windows 10). The macbook only has usb-c inputs, so I got an adapter that takes several different types of inputs and has usb-c output. Normally, I use it for my monitor (an hdmi connection) and my mouse (a usb connection). for convenience, I just move the adapter between machines when I switch them out (working from home, eyyy). The whole setup is still fine on the mac, but suddenly, apparently without changing anything, the usb input *only* has stopped working on my windows machine. I have tried multiple different usb devices, none of which connect. All of devices I tested still work when plugged in via one of the normal usb ports, but I'd like to be able to use the adapter since I don't have many ports to spare. I don't really know what other information to include here, so just ask if more is needed

Comment: Have you taken a look at **Device Manager**? Deletion & re-detection of a device is often the quick fix for issues like thes.

Comment: I've tried the "uninstall device" option from the manager, but after that trying to plug it in through the adapter didn't do anything. It did work again after plugging back in through a built-in port. Of note, though, is that this problem is not unique to a specific device (I've tried a few others besides my mouse), so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: But the _adapter itself_ should appar as a device at some level. It might become more apparent if you select your `USB Root Hub` and then select `View  > Devices by Connection`.

Comment: ah, that's done it! Thank you. Didn't even know the manager made that distinction.

Comment: Great! I'm going to write that up as an answer, and then you can mark it as "**Answer**"

Answer (score 0):

When trouble-shooting hardwware issues, the second-most common fix (after "Is it plugged in?") is to delete & then re-detect the device in question via **Device Manager**.

In your case, you want to look for the adapater itself. Since it's connected via a usb-c port, it will probably be easier to find if you select the **`USB Root Hub`** and then switch the view to **`Devices by Connection`**

[image]

When you locate your device, uninstall it:

[image]

Some deletions seem to trigger auatomatic re-detecgtion, some don't. Let any automatic re-detection take place, then re-start the computer.